# How to query optimize many to many association with SQL?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

### Scenario:

Invoice has many purchase_orders and purchase_orders has many invoices. Intermediate table is npayment_links which has foreign key invoice_id, purchase_order_id.

### Tech Stack

Rails 5.x,
Postgresql

Here is my sample data

### invoices

| id | name | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | sample.pdf | archived |
| 101 | sample1.pdf | archived |
| 102 | sample2.pdf | archived |
| 103 | sample2.pdf | active |
| 104 | sample2.pdf | active |

### purchase_orders

| id | title |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | first po |
| 2 | second po |
| 3 | third po |
| 4 | fourth po |

### npayment_links

| id | purchase_order_id | invoice_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 100 |
| 2 | 1 | 101 |
| 3 | 1 | 102 |
| 4 | 2 | 100 |
| 5 | 2 | 103 |
| 6 | 3 | 104 |
| 7 | 4 | 100 |

I am expecting query which returns all purchase_orders whose all invoices are archived.

- If you see npayment_links

  - purchase_orders with id=1 is associated with 3 invoices (100, 101, 102), which has all archived invoices.
  - purchase_orders with id=2 is associated with 2 invoices (100, 103), which has archived and active invoices.
  - purchase_orders with id=3 is associated with 1 invoice (104), which has active invoice.
  - purchase_orders with id=4 is associated with 1 invoice (100), which has archived invoice.

I'm searching for Sql query which returns PO list which contains all archived invoices.

### Expected purchase_orders

| id | title |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | first po |
| 4 | fourth po |

### I have achieved above issue with Rails AR way. But, I'm searching for some Sql query to achieve this:

```
Invoice.find(100).purchase_orders.each do |po|
  if po.invoices.all? { |inv| inv.archived? }
    # po.update(status: :done) # I will do some operation here. And If there are 1000s of data in which each PO again have many invoices, I might feel this will add query complexity. So, I am searching for some optimized solution here.
  end
end
```

Any feedback would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use JOINS to connect your tables. Then you can simply query for all purchase orders that have archived invoices and compare that to second select with `EXCEPT` that would give you POs that have active invoices. By using EXCEPT as a result you will get all rows that appear in first select without those that appear in second select.

```
SELECT 
    po.* 
FROM 
    purchase_orders po
    JOIN npayment_links pl on po.id = pl.purchase_order_id
    JOIN invoices i on pl.invoice_id = i.id
WHERE i.status LIKE 'archived'
EXCEPT
SELECT 
    po.* 
FROM 
    purchase_orders po
    JOIN npayment_links pl on po.id = pl.purchase_order_id
    JOIN invoices i on pl.invoice_id = i.id
WHERE i.status LIKE 'active'
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/70Q6SFdR)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the most optimized solution but the following should work:

```
PurchaseOrder.where.not(id: 
  PurchaseOrder
    .select(:id)
    .joins(:invoices)
    .where.not(invoices: {status: 'archived'})
)
```

The thought process is find all the Purchase Orders who's id is not in a list of Purchase Order ids with a status that is something other than archived and  this will result in the following SQL

```
SELECT 
  purchase_orders.* 
FROM 
  purchase_orders
WHERE 
  purchase_orders.id NOT IN (
    SELECT 
      purchase_orders.id
    FROM 
      purchase_orders
      INNER JOIN invoice_links ON invoice_links.purchase_order_id = purchase_orders.id 
      INNER JOIN invoices ON invoices.id = invoice_links.invoice_id 
    WHERE 
      invoices.status <> 'archived'
)
```

This will also return Purchase Orders that do not have any invoices. If having an invoice is also a requirement you can simply add `joins(:invoices)` e.g.

```
PurchaseOrder
  .joins(:invoices)
  .where.not(id: 
    PurchaseOrder
      .select(:id)
      .joins(:invoices)
      .where.not(invoices: {status: 'archived'})
)
```

**Note**: Your question states the Join Table is `invoice_links` and then references `npayment_links` so I am unsure which is the actual join table. For my example I will assume the join table is `invoice_links` as that makes more logical sense; however, provided the associations are setup correctly in the ORM, this assumption has no impact on the functionality of the proposed solution.

Comment: Yes, query you wrote does not matter the join table name, that's okay. Thanks for your feedback. I'm analyzing both answers.